# the games on my sony ericsson live (ics) keeps on crashing

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

two days ago my phone was alright ,but now when i open any game it loads and crashes .im not able to play any game.would be appreciated if solution was for root users without clearing game data or factory reset.

Answer (score 1):

There might be insufficient working memory.. (memory is being used by other application that you are not using..). to fix it go to Setting>Applications>Manage Applications, Click on the Runnning Tab. now Force close applications or games that are running but not needed. And dont forget to force close the games/apps that has this issues. I hope this helps.